# Pthread Condition variables are a replacement for continuous polling, is it true?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex

i have learned that pthread condition variables provides the facility to replace polling. Without condition variables, the programmer would need to have threads continually polling (possibly in a critical section), to check if the condition is met. This can be very resource consuming since the thread would be continuously busy in this activity. A condition variable is a way to achieve the same goal without polling. But why in the code i need to check a variable continuously whether i use conditions or not. Then what is the benefit of using the conditional variable?

```
  pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);

  while (count<COUNT_LIMIT) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
    printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Condition signal received.\n", my_id);
    count += 125;
    printf("watch_count(): thread %ld count now = %d.\n", my_id, count);
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
```

Now in [the above example](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) i see that i need to poll whether i use the condition variable or not.  then what is the benefit of condition variable here in the sense that *polling is not required?* The mutex can achieve the necessary synchronization, with an if(count check.

So, why i will use the conditional variable here to replace polling on a variable? it is still here in use. And why i cannot achieve the same thing here with mutex and a simple if clause? And finally I want to have a clear idea about what problems conditional variables actually solve?

Comment: the above code won't even compile. And what makes you think that the intention is "polling"? Why don't you see it as a counter of events? Anyway, why don't you put some real code and describe some real problem?

Comment: @littleadv I took the example from here, https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables why are you saying it wont compile? please tell me about the counter of events as you mentioned. I want to have a clear idea.

Comment: Um, it obviously can't compile. It's missing variable declarations, close braces, etc., not to mention it's a partial fragment of a function.

Comment: You might have taken it from that page, but you failed to copy/paste it correctly (missing a closing brace). Well, value added service, I added it for you. BTW it is never wrong to attribute where you taken stuff from. It will help others that want to help you with your question and makes you look more creditable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the positive opinion. I am new to posix threads and I am having confusions about some features of pthread library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop in the example is either never runs or runs once, it never loops (unless pthread fails in some way - and for that its a loop and not a simple `if`). Read the comments:

> Also, note that if COUNT_LIMIT is reached before this routine is run
>   by   the waiting thread, the loop will be skipped to prevent
>   pthread_cond_wait   from never returning.

It is a precaution for the case when the condition has already been met by the time you get there, so that you won't wait forever.

Once the condition variable is awaken, the `count` variable is incremented so that the loop will exit (incremented by 125, `COUNT_LIMIT` is 12).

This is a multi-threaded program. You can't look at a single detached function and try to understand what it does, ignoring the other threads.